# Visual Studio cannot find symbol and class doesn't show up in solution explorer although it is in directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, perforce

Visual studio is saying that the type or namespace name "EquipmentWebPage" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

This file, EquipmentWebPage.cs, isn't showing up in the solution explorer either; it's like it has ceased to exist.  But, if I try to create a new EquipmentWebpage.cs file, I get the following error:

A file with the name "EquipmentWebPage.cs" already exists and is open in an editor.  Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first.

Also, if I go to file, open existing file and browse to the src folder, I can see the file and open it.  But when I try to rebuild the solution, it is still giving me the error that it cannot find that file.

Does anybody have any ideas of how to fix this, or should I just delete the file and re-add it?

Additional details:
This issue started after I committed my code to perforce and pulled down latest revision.  Perforce didn't say I had any conflicts or problems, and perforce still contains this file and others can pull it down and build the solution successfully; it seems completely local to my machine.  I have removed my entire solution from source control to see if that helped, but nothing changed.

Also tried:
Making all files in src read-only
making all files in src not read-only

Edit:
equipmentWebPage.cs is a file of my own creation, not from a dll or other outside source

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That just means that the file exists, but isn't included in your project.

Click Show all files on the Solution Explorer toolbar, then right-click the missing file and click Include in Project.

Comment: I don't have the option to Include in Project.  I do have the option to exclude from project, so I guess it is included in the project somehow?

Comment: Actually your solution might have worked.  I went into the .csproj file and deleted the references to the missing files and then followed your instructions and it seems to be working

Comment: Alternatively, if it is locally on your drive you can just try to add it into the project Add -> Existing Item